# When we should rollback an edit contrary to author input?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

Shog's guidance and the help page about editing are very clear and simple on how to edit someone's post:

> - clarify meaning without changing it
> - always respect the original author

Now, how does that affect rollbacks? AFAIK, the author always have the power to roll back edits on its own answers if he wishes, but as seen [in other communities](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4413/editing-an-answer-to-add-code-example-and-then-it-was-reverted#comment7525_4414), if the edit is an improvement upon the post we may forego the OP's wishes and force the higher quality revision to stay. Should we do the same in the opposite direction? Should we forego OP wishes and **force the lower quality revision to stay**?

For me, that doesn't make sense, since we are building a repository of high quality answers (I say answer, because that's what it says, but the same applies to questions), doing actions that *reduce the quality and/or usefulness of a post* goes directly against such goal, but I would like to hear well reasoned arguments about it.

Comment: Alternative title: Lots of red and green! I need to rollback!

Comment: Forcing an edit down the unwilling throat of a post owner is bizarre, unfriendly and completely unnecessary.  Anybody can use the rights that the author implicitly provided, they can derive their own post from his.

Comment: @HansPassant that depends. We rollback edits made by OP when he defaces his post, out of respect for the content. If someone improves my post, I would welcome it. Now, if someone improves my post and a third party unimproves it... well, I would wonder what is wrong in the head of that user. You should know more than anyone about that since you do a hand off approach to your own post, unwilling to maintain them. Shouldn't the community help you out in maintaining your content?

Comment: That comment does not seem to have anything to do with "contrary to author input", the premise of the question.

Comment: @HansPassant actually, it follows the premise of your comment and your overall attitude to the topic to a T.

Answer (score 2):

The most common case that I've notice this happen is when the OP decides to destroy all evidence, and sabotages their own post.

At that point, the post is often edit-locked and rolled back to before the vandalism.

I've also seen it happen when the OP asks a question, gets answers, then significantly alters the question to the point the answers do not make sense.

To a degree, the quality of a post is relative to the reader. It's quite possible that OP was trying to ask something but didn't get the point quite across. Someone then comes along with good intentions and assumes that they know what the OP meant - but is wrong. At that point you have a high quality question - but not the one that OP meant to ask. I could imagine a confused OP rolling back under those circumstances, though they may be subject to my third paragraph leaving the OP even more confused.

I think the status quo is that if you make an edit and it gets rejected - just move on. Unless the OP is obviously sabotaging, then it's their question. They can present it how they like. This may come at the consequence of having lower quality answers - but that's their choice.